# Squares of Primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

If we let $f(n)$ denote the sum of all the divisors of the integer $n$, how many integers $i$ exist such that $1 \le i \le 2010$ and $f(i) = 1 + \sqrt{i} + i$?

How do I find the solution to this problem? Here are my thoughts.

Thought Process 1: Find all perfect squares (of primes) less than 2010. Would that be correct?

I think that the answer is 14 ?

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant just 14. Sorry for my excitement.

Comment: But yes, I think your argument is correct. I could write up an answer, but it would be nearly identical to the [last answer I gave you](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2532716/15500).

Comment: There's no hope unless $i=n^2$ is a square. In that case, $1$, $n$ and $n^2$ are certainly factors....

Comment: We find $2^2,3^2,5^2,7^2,11^2,13^2,17^2,19^2,\ldots ,43^2$. So indeed $14$.